# iOS code to identify metal support in runtime?

Tags: ios, objective-c, metal

Usually, I use the below code to identify the iOS version of the device.

```
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion floatValue] >= 8.0)
```

In a similar way, I'm trying to find Metal support for the device. Metal is supported for Apple devices with the A7 (or better) GPU and iOS 8.0.

This is the way I expect my code to work:

```
if (MetalSupported == true) {
  // metal programming
} else {
  // opengles2 programming
}
```

How do I get the value for the Boolean variable `MetalSupported` ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's good that you're looking for something specific to Metal — generally, iOS version checks and hardware name checks are fragile, because they rely on your app knowing all of the OS versions and devices that could ever run it. If Apple were to go back and release an iOS 7.x version that added Metal support (okay, seems unlikely), or a device that supports Metal but isn't one of the hardware names you're looking at (seems much more likely), you'd be stuck having to track all of those things down and update your app to manage them.

Anyway, the best way to check whether the device you're running on is Metal  enough for your awesome graphics code? Just try to get a `MTLDevice` object:

```
id<MTLDevice> device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice();
if (device) {
    // ready to rock 
} else {
    // back to OpenGL
}
```

Note that just testing for the presence of a Metal framework class doesn't help — those classes are there on any device running iOS 8 (all the way back to iPhone 4s & iPad 2), regardless of whether that device has a Metal-capable GPU.

In Simulator, Metal is supported as of iOS 13 / tvOS 13 when running on macOS 10.15. Use the same strategy: call `MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()`. If it returns an object then your simulator code is running in an environment where the simulator is hardware-accelerated. If it returns `nil` then you're running on an older simulator or in an environment where Metal is not available.

Comment: no this not true, i saw on some mac that MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice return a device BUT metal was not supported on this mac

Answer (score 8):

On iOS, you should just check `MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()`.  If it returns a valid device, you’re good to go.  On macOS, you need to be careful; use `[MTLCopyAllDevices() count]` to determine if you have any supported metal devices available.

You should avoid using `MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()` on macOS because that can force a mux switch to the discrete GPU (eg: if you're dealing with a laptop with automatic graphics switching between a discrete and integrated graphics).

Comment: MTLCopyAllDevices is only available in macOS.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/1433367-mtlcopyalldevices

Comment: Ah, true.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ricster explained clearly about all the methods to identify the device which supports metal at runtime. If you cannot use MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice() in your class by including metal libraries, use device informations(iOS version,gpu/cpu architecture),but you need to consider all the cases explained by Ricster when using device informations.

```
void deviceConfigurations(){
        size_t size;
        cpu_type_t type;
        cpu_subtype_t subtype;
        size = sizeof(type);
        sysctlbyname("hw.cputype", &type, &size, NULL, 0);

        size = sizeof(subtype);
        sysctlbyname("hw.cpusubtype", &subtype, &size, NULL, 0);
}
```

Use Subtype and type variable to identify device and other informations.

Comment: This would mean keeping a list of all the devices that can run Metal... And updating it whenever Apple releases a new device. If your app is built with the iOS 8 or later SDK, which it needs to be for you to use Metal, then `MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice` is there for you to call--at no cost.

Answer (score -2):

I think the best way is to try to get one of the metal classes.

```
Class metalDeviceClass = NSClassFromString(@"MTLDevice");
BOOL isMetalAvailable = metalDeviceClass != nil;
if (isMetalAvailable) {
    NSLog(@"Metal available");
} else {
    NSLog(@"Metal not available");
}
```

Comment: 1. `MTLDevice` isn't a class; it's a protocol, so this test will fail even on Metal-supported devices. 2. The classes in the Metal framework are still there on non-Metal-supported devices (you just can't do anything with them), so testing for their presence won't tell you if you can render with Metal. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29903799/957768).

Comment: Yep, thanks for pointing. Actually I didn't check if it a class or protocol. My point was to check one of the classes availability. Your solution is correct.