# MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice() returning nil on iPad with iOS 10.3

Tags: swift, metal

I am trying to do some fluid simulation with Google's Liquidfun and Metal, using an iPad running iOS 10.3. However, the initial call to MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice() is returning nil.

I have the following console log, so I know that Metal is supported on the iPad, but I am not sure how to debug this issue.

```
2018-07-02 20:28:44.547645-0500 chem-lab-practical[529:464344] [DYMTLInitPlatform].
platform initialization successful 2018-07-02 20:28:44.781763-0500 
chem-lab-practical[529:464294] Metal GPU Frame Capture Enabled 2018-07-02 
20:28:44.783609-0500 chem-lab-practical[529:464294] Metal API Validation Enabled 
(lldb)
```

I have not found similar questions on stack overflow and am a beginner to using Metal, so I am not sure how to begin to debug this issue.

Comment: Assuming you’re running on an actual device and not the simulator, the reason might be that you’re using an older iPad that is not Metal compatible. This would be the iPad Mini 2 or the original iPad Air. Anything older doesn’t have Metal support.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the case.

Answer (score 1):

So... I guess I wasn't looking hard enough because I've found an answer here ([iOS code to identify metal support in runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29790663/ios-code-to-identify-metal-support-in-runtime)).

According to the post,

> Note that just testing for the presence of a Metal framework class doesn't help — those classes are there on any device running iOS 8 (all the way back to iPhone 4s & iPad 2), regardless of whether that device has a Metal-capable GPU.

For reference, this is a list of Metal compatible iOS devices (https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/HardwareGPUInformation/HardwareGPUInformation.html)